# How to get a comma separated list of x items starting from y from another comma seperated list

Tags: php, arrays, list, explode, implode

Say I have a list `Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco`.
I want to have a list starting on the 3rd item, and have 5 items in total. That means I want to have `England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan`.

How can I do this on PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert string to array like

```
$str = "Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco";
$array = explode(",",$str);
```

and then use `array_slice` to skip first 2 items

`print_r(implode(",",array_slice($array,2)));`

Answer (score 1):

You can set limit to explode function (the 3rd argument) and get the last item of the result array

```
$str = 'Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco';
echo $result = explode(',', $str, 3)[2]; //England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco
```

From the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>   maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of
>   string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$list = "Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco";
$listArray = explode(",",$list);
print_r($listArray);
$startlist = 3; // Here you can set where you have start
if($startlist<count($listArray)){
    print_r(implode(",",array_slice($listArray,$startlist)));
}else{
    echo "Start limit exceed length of string";
}

?>
```

Output
For positive scenario set `$startlist = 3;`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Poland
    [1] => USA
    [2] => England
    [3] => China
    [4] => Uruguay
    [5] => Spain
    [6] => Taiwan
    [7] => Monaco
)
China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco
```

for Negative scenario set `$startlist = 8;`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Poland
    [1] => USA
    [2] => England
    [3] => China
    [4] => Uruguay
    [5] => Spain
    [6] => Taiwan
    [7] => Monaco
)
Start limit exceed length of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way as a function, returns the new list if the new list can be returned, else returns false....

```
<?php

function formatList ( $l, $c, $s, $r )
{
    $s -= 1;

    $p = explode ( $c, $l );

    return ( $r + $s ) <= count ( $p ) ? implode ( $c, array_slice ( $p, $s, $r ) ) : FALSE;
}   

$list = 'Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco';

$split_on = ',';

$start_on = 3;

$return_total = 5;

echo formatList ( $list, $split_on, $start_on, $return_total ); // should be in a if(), just for example


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your 5 items `England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan`, you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in combination with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and specify 2 for the `offset` and specify 5 for the `length`.

For example:

```
$str = "Poland,USA,England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan,Monaco";
$result = array_slice(explode(',', $str),2, 5)
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => England
    [1] => China
    [2] => Uruguay
    [3] => Spain
    [4] => Taiwan
)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/ImA3T)

Then you might also use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get the result as in your example:

```
echo implode(',', $result);
// England,China,Uruguay,Spain,Taiwan
```